# Relatives and absolute url when doing http.get in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, rest, typescript

I'm new to Angular and it's being hard work to do some things.
I'm using the latest angular ( version 4 ).
I have this scenario :

1. My backend rest services are in `baseurl/contextWS`
2. My angular application is in `baseurl/contextFront`
3. The base tag href attribute is pointing to /contextFront
4. Both the angular application and the backend are in the same server (baseurl)
5. The angular application is embedded in an iframe (because is referenced by another application) .

Now lets say I want to call to `baseurl/contextWS/myservice` from the angular application.
How can I do this ?

I can't do `this.http.get('/contextWS/myservice')` because from the angular app this will translate to
`baseurl/contextFront/contextWS/myservice` which is wrong.

I tried to build the url like this :

```
var url 'http://' + location.host +':' + location.port + '/contextWS/myservice';
this.http.get(url);
```

This works very well in my application, but when my app is referenced in the iframe it gives me some error like "undefined".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the iframe and if it works?

Comment: I can't do that because the iframe is in another application in another server and this is maintained by other team. Removing the iframe is not an option. I would like to know if there is some way to obtain the server and port where the front end is hosted. I've tried with "location.host" but it doesn't work maybe because of the iframe